# Attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute - No more help needed

Tags: pygame, python-2.5

I am new to programming and I keep getting this error in my code. Here is my full code:
    import sys, pygame, math;
    from pygame.locals import *;
    from sys import exit
    pygame.init()

```
blk = pygame.Color(0,0,0)
BG = ('BG.png')
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
#mousec = pygame.image.load(mouse_c).convert_alpha()
B_G = pygame.image.load(BG).convert_alpha()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
Shrek = pygame.image.load('SHORK.png').convert_alpha()
Shrek_Rect = Shrek.get_rect()

class Shork(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load('SHORK.png')
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    self.x = 62
    self.y = 50
    self.direction = "down"

  def Moving(self):

    if self.direction == "right":
     self.x += 2
    elif self.direction == "left":
     self.x -= 2
    elif self.direction == "down":
     self.y += 2
    elif self.direction == "up":
     self.y -= 2

  def Path(self): # Moves the "SHORK" image on the screen

    if self.x == 62 and self.y == 538:
     self.direction = "right"

    if self.x == 246 and self.y == 538:
     self.direction = "up"

    if self.x == 246 and self.y == 366:
     self.direction = "left"

    if self.x == 176 and self.y == 366:
     self.direction = "up"

    if self.x == 176 and self.y == 114:
     self.direction = "right"

    if self.x == 530 and self.y == 114:
     self.direction = "down"

    if self.x == 530 and self.y == 366:
     self.direction = "left"

    if self.x == 460 and self.y == 366:
     self.direction = "down"

    if self.x == 460 and self.y == 538:
     self.direction = "right"

    if self.x == 644 and self.y == 538:
     self.direction = "up"
    if self.y == 0:
     sys.exit()

Shork = Shork()

Run = True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            print("test1")
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
            print("test3")
    while Run:
        fpsclock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():

         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Run = False
    pos = pygame.Shrek_Rect
    angle = 360-math.atan2(pos[1]-300,pos[0]-400)*180/math.pi
    rotimage = pygame.transform.rotate(B_G,angle)
    screen.fill(blk)
    Shork.Moving() 
    Shork.Path()
    screen.blit(Shork.image, (Shork.x, Shork.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    rect = rotimage.get_rect(center=(400,300))
    screen.blit(rotimage,rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    #Rotates the BG image on the screen
```

This is where my error occurs:

```
    pos = pygame.Shrek_Rect
    angle = 360-math.atan2(pos[1]-300,pos[0]-400)*180/math.pi
    rotimage = pygame.transform.rotate(B_G,angle)
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turny.py", line 96, in (module)
    pos = pygame.Shork_Rect
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shrek_Rect'
```

The point of the program is to rotate the BG image towards the SHORK image as it moves on the screen. I repurposed this code from some old code that was meant to make BG follow the cursor. I am stuck on this error and cannot figure it out.

Also, if you replace Shrek_Rect with "mouse.get_pos()" where the error is BG will follow the player mouse.

Comment: I don't see `pygame.Shrek_Rect` defined anywhere, and pygame does not have any Attribute `Shrek_Rect` in my glance of the documentation. Did you confuse it with `pygame.Rect`?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh it is defined on line 11 :)

Comment: Ah didn't see that. Well, that solves my the issue :D

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh than you for the answer!

Comment: If the answer works and solves your question, please consider marking the answer as closed so others know the question has been answered. If my response does not answer your question, of course, please do not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is one with namespaces. `Shrek_Rect` is not defined within `pygame`, it's defined within the local namespace.

Try changing:

```
pos = pygame.Shrek_Rect
```

To:

```
pos = Shrek_Rect
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I really appreciate the answer. :)